# Can I impute a variable conditional on another?

Tags: stata

I am trying to impute the data about whether someone is born in the UK from wave 1 to wave 2. I suspect the `egen` function would work but I am not sure what the code would look like?

[image: Table]

As you can see, I need to assign the same `born in the uk` response for person id 1 in wave 1 to wave 2.

I know I could do it by reshaping the dataset to a wide format but do you know whether there is any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Stata FAQ [as accessible here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/).

You can copy downwards in the dataset without creating any new variables.

```
bysort id (wave) : replace born_in_uk = born_in_uk[_n-1] if missing(born_in_uk)
```

`mipolate` (SSC) has a `groupwise` option that checks for there being more than one non-missing value. Search within www.statalist.org for mentions.

Note that `egen` is a command, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether here born in the UK is numeric with labels or string. But, what if you would do something like:

```
encode born_in_UK, gen(born_num)

bysort person_id: egen born_num2=mean(born_num)
drop born_num
rename born_num2 born_num
```

The idea is to think of the repeating personal ids as groups and use the mean function to fill the missing values in the group. I think this should work.